# Increase HDFS size in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have a hadoop cluster with HDFS of 100gb , which I would like to increase the size to 500gb. I have increased the hard disk space in the nodes. I need to add that extra space to HDFS. The extra space is mounted on `/data` partition

I have manually created the `/data/dfs/dn` directory and then editted the `hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/data/dfs/dn,/data/dfs/dn</value>
</property>
```

`/home/hadoop/data/dfs/dn` is the default location and want to add the `/data/dfs/nn` space to the datanode. The above code resulted in zero HDFS space.

Is there any way to increase the HDFS size without formatting the Namenode?